# django form_isvalid() returns error 'Enter a whole number' for float field

Tags: python, django, nginx

I have following lines in models.py:

```
            ('total_marks_tenth', models.IntegerField()),
            ('obtained_marks_tenth', models.FloatField()),
            ('board_twelvth', models.TextField(default='')),
            ('subjects_twelvth', models.TextField(default='')),
            ('total_marks_twelvth', models.IntegerField()),
            ('obtained_marks_twelvth', models.FloatField()),
```

I ran `manage.py makemigarations` and `manage.py migrate`. The entry in database also shows that it is a double field. But, while running the app on nginx server I am getting following error:
[image]

Please help me to solve this.

Edit:

I am using modelform in my application:

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = '__all__'
```

Surprisingly, when I am running the same app with the same configuration on my local system, it's working fine. But, after hosting it on nginx server, I am getting the error described.

This is template code:

```
<div class='form-group internal'>
                        <div class='col-md-6'>

                            {% render_field form.obtained_marks_tenth class='form-control' placeholder='Obtained Marks' type='text' %}
                            {% if form.obtained_marks_tenth.errors %}
                            <div class="alert alert-danger tpad">
                                {{ form.obtained_marks_tenth.errors.as_text }}
                            </div>

                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

The view code is:

```
def apply(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StudentForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            name = request.POST.get("name")

            form.save()
            print "Form is saved successfully."
            return render(request, 'success.html',{'name' : name})
        else:
            print "Something went wrong"
            print form.errors
            return render(request, 'apply.html',{'form' : form})


    return render(request, 'apply.html',{'form' : StudentForm()})
```

Comment: show your template and view code

Comment: Give me a minute. Thanks for the reply. Here is the link of the website : http://jamiaalumniusa.com/apply/

Comment: Make sure you have restarted your server (e.g. uwsgi/gunicorn) after updating the code and running `migrate`.

Comment: I have restarted using command : sudo service nginx restart.

Comment: You haven't said how you are deploying Django (e.g. uwsgi/gunicorn). If nginx is a reverse proxy, then restarting nginx *will not* restart the Django application.

Comment: So, how can I achieve that.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Now, everything is working fine. Please post your comment as answer, so that I accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have changed the code in production, you have to restart your server for the changes to take effect.

If you are deploying with Apache and mod_wsgi, then restarting Apache should work.

If you are deploying with Nginx (or another server) as a reverse proxy, then restarting it will not work. You need to restart your Django server e.g. gunicorn or uWSGI.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was struggling with the issue since two days.

Answer (score 2):

This error only present in `IntegerField`, you probably mixed up field names somewhere and using integer field in a form.

Answer (score 0):

This problem arises from forms.py only. I the forms, you might have used a wrong argument in that field.